# Select first element that doesn't have a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to write a selector that targets the first element that doesn't have a specific class.

```
<ul>
<li class="someClass">item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li> <-- I want to select this
<li class="someClass">item 3</li>
<li>item 4</li>
</ul>
```

I know how to select all elements that doesn't have "someClass":

```
$('li not:(.someClass)').dostuff();
```

But I don't know how to only select the first element that doesn't have "someClass".

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('li:not(.someClass):first')
```

Here's a working demo: http://jsbin.com/arosa

Comment: I think this is a nicer solution than using the eq(0) filter - probably more efficient

Answer (score 1):

see http://docs.jquery.com/Core/eq

```
$('li not:(.someClass)').eq(0).dostuff();
```

but as pointed out its probably

```
$('li:not(.someClass)').eq(0).dostuff();
```

whatever `eq(0)` will select the first element

Answer (score 1):

You just have a typo, the syntax is `:not()`:

```
$('li:not(.someClass)').eq(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
alert($('li:not(li.someClass)').eq(0).html());
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('li first-child not:(.someClass)').dostuff()
```

Comment: I *think* this would target the first child IF it doesn't have someClass rather than the first child that doesn't have some class...but I've not tested it (or my solution either!)